# Type of error: get_dataset_names() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

I have clean dataset which is stored in csv file twt_clean_final.csv. It is data collected from twitter.  I need to build plot with data and I wanted to use sns.PairGrid(), but getting error.

```
twt_clean = pd.read_csv('twt_clean_final.csv')
g = sns.get_dataset_names('twt_clean')
g = sns.PairGrid(twt_clean)
g.map(plt.scatter);
```

The error is following:

```
TypeError Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-134-43fa2c40408f> in <module>
     1 twt_clean = pd.read_csv('twt_clean_final.csv')
----> 2 g = sns.get_dataset_names('twt_clean')
      3 g = sns.PairGrid(twt_clean)
      4 g.map(plt.scatter);
TypeError: get_dataset_names() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given
```

**How do I fix it?**

I want to build a plot for current dataset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function `sns.get_dataset_names()` is for one to check what datasets are available for plotting, for example:

```
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

sns.get_dataset_names()

['anscombe',
 'attention',
 'brain_networks',
 'car_crashes',
 'diamonds',
 'dots',
 'exercise',
 'flights',
 'fmri',
 'gammas',
 'iris',
 'mpg',
 'planets',
 'tips',
 'titanic']
```

And we can use one of them to plot:

```
data = sns.load_dataset('anscombe')
g = sns.FacetGrid(data,col="dataset",hue="dataset")
g.map(plt.scatter, "x", "y")
```

[image]

Since you already have a dataset, you can just plot:

```
twt_clean = pd.DataFrame(np.random.normal(0,1,(100,3)),columns=["A","B","C"])
g = sns.PairGrid(twt_clean)
g.map_diag(plt.hist)
g.map_upper(plt.scatter)
g.map_lower(sns.kdeplot)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

From the error you received, `sns.get_dataset_names()` takes no argument at all.  I guess you can omit it. The rest should work:

```
twt_clean = pd.read_csv('twt_clean_final.csv')

g = sns.PairGrid(twt_clean)

g.map(plt.scatter)
```

Comment: Thank you! This also helps to get plot without error.